# postgreSQL 9.6 64bits mistake backup

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, dump, corruption

Could someone help me with this error?

```
pg_dump: reading schemas 
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables 
pg_dump:sanity check failed, parent table OID 841379 of sequence OID 841385
not found Traceback (last most recent call):
```

I would like to know the causes of this problem. I'm trying to map out what might be causing this inconsistency. I was able to identify this table in a client and there was an error in the Id_seq, as it was not something important, I deleted it in the type and class

```
delete from pg_class where relname = 'modulo_detalhe_id_seq' and relfilenode = '841385'
delete from pg_type where typname = 'modulo_detalhe_id_seq' and typrelid = '841385'
```

Can anyone give me insight, what could be causing this issue, this was after a software update

```
delete from pg_class where relname = 'modulo_detalhe_id_seq' and relfilenode = '841385'
delete from pg_type where typname = 'modulo_detalhe_id_seq' and typrelid = '841385'
```

Comment: This needs more information, **add as update to question** 1) The complete `pg_dump` command. 2) What followed; `not found Traceback (last most recent call):`? 3) What was the software update?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.